FluentUI React Component Set AvatarProps background to white
I'm using fluent ui react components. I want to have the AvatarImage with a whitebackground.
const avatar: AvatarProps = { image: { src: imageSrc } };
No matter what I do I cannot seem to find a way to get it to white.
